# Filter JSON arrays with nested array filters combined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm writing a JS code that has to filter JSON data based on a condition. I've posted a question yesterday but without trying anything at [How to filter data from a json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279650/how-to-filter-data-from-a-json-response?noredirect=1#comment83550496_48279650), it was down voted and since I didn't try anything I am good with it. I've tried using the filter, but unfortunately I've got an array with in array and here I'm stuck. Here is my code.

```
var arr2 = [
  [{
    "max": "0.685",
    "target_state": "6",
    "ingredients": "a",
    "rule_no": "7",
    "id": "18"
  }, {
    "max": "14",
    "target_state": "6",
    "ingredients": "b",
    "rule_no": "7",
    "id": "17"
  }],
  [{
    "max": "14",
    "target_state": "7",
    "ingredients": "b",
    "rule_no": "8",
    "id": "19"
  }, {
    "max": "1.36",
    "target_state": "7",
    "ingredients": "a",
    "rule_no": "8",
    "id": "20"
  }]
];

var result = arr2.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
  })
  .filter(function(obj) {
    return (obj.max == 0.685 && obj.ingredients === "a")
  });

alert(JSON.stringify(result[0].target_state));
```

when I run this code, I get the result as "6".

But here my condition is something like this `((obj.max == 0.685 && obj.ingredients === "a") && (obj.max == 14 && obj.ingredients === "b"))`, but this is not returning anything.

Here the expected output is `"6"`.

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vjt45xv4/14/

Please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you also share expected output based on max and ingredients value?

Comment: It should be `(...) || (...)`. If `obj.max` is 0.685, it cannot be 14. Always try to write an English version of condition. It will always help in solving them. `((obj.max == 0.685 && obj.ingredients === "a") && (obj.max == 14 && obj.ingredients === "b"))` is interpreted as *`max` value should be `0.685` and `ingredients` should be `a` **and** `max` value should be `14` and `ingredients` should be `b`*

Comment: Are you trying to select the first, second, and third elements, or just the first and second? Also, I would suggest not using `==` in order to compare a number to a string. If you want to compare a string value to a number, parse the string: `Number(obj.max) === 0.685`

Comment: @gurvinder372, updated my question with expected result

Comment: @JLRishe, Here I've an array like this `[[{}, {}],[{}, {}]]` and here I want to check the internal arrays matching the condition(both the internal arrays should satisfy it) and return the result.

Comment: @user3872094 So you want the result to contain the internal arrays that matched the condition, not the individual objects that matched it? Also, I'm confused when you say that both internal arrays match this condition: `((obj.max == 0.685 && obj.ingredients === "a") && (obj.max == 14 && obj.ingredients === "b"))`. Setting aside for a moment that this condition itself is guaranteed to be `false`, the second array doesn't have an element with an `obj.max` value of 0.685.

Comment: @JLRishe here is the case, I search for the internal arrays `[[{},{}]]` to match `max` as given and `ingredients` also as given, if both the internal arrays matches the condition, then I want it to print the output. In my case I'm checking for `(obj.max == 0.685 && obj.ingredients === "a")` and `(obj.max == 14 && obj.ingredients === "b")`, this is basically the 1st internal array.  it should return the value as `6` as the `target_state` is `6`

Comment: Please clarify what you want `result` to be after the filtering is done. Saying you want to get the value `6` at the end tells us very little about what you want the process to actually do. I'm still having trouble understanding your description of the desired behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163307/discussion-between-user3872094-and-jlrishe).

Comment: @JLRishe, first loop through the internal arrays `[[],[]]`, and from this arrays, search for the condition `[{},{}]`. and once the condition is met, I get the internal array, and for both the first internal array, the `target_state` is `6`, I want to print this out

Comment: @JLRishe, I understood that this is a bit confusing, can we please take it over chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve here.

How about the following one? It worked for me.

```
var result = arr2
  .filter(function(objs) {
    return ((objs.find((obj) => obj.ingredients === "a" ).max == 0.685) 
&& (objs.find((obj) => obj.ingredients === "b" ).max == 14));
  })
  .reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for this friend. But I'm matching for both, not either

Comment: @user3872094 You want objects matching both the conditions within sub array?

Comment: Yes Nabin, you are perfect... That's my requirement

Comment: @user3872094 I now understand  what you are trying to achieve. I have provided the solution. Please check.

Comment: You are awesome Bro ... This was what I was expecting :)

Comment: @user3872094 Great to know it helped you.